# What does @param and @return mean in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, parameters

I'm just starting out a question on leetcode and i'm just wondering what the syntax of a bit of code means.

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode
#     attr_accessor :val, :next
#     def initialize(val)
#         @val = val
#         @next = nil
#     end
# end

# @param {ListNode} l1
# @param {ListNode} l2
# @return {ListNode}

def add_two_numbers(l1, l2)

end
```

I'm having trouble understanding what this particular part means.

```
# @param {ListNode} l1
# @param {ListNode} l2
# @return {ListNode}
```

Comment: In ruby, it's just a comment and has no effect whatsoever.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From https://yardoc.org/:

> YARD is a documentation generation tool for the Ruby programming
>   language. It enables the user to generate consistent, usable
>   documentation that can be exported to a number of formats very easily,
>   and also supports extending for custom Ruby constructs such as custom
>   class level definitions.

```rb
# @param {ListNode} l1
# @param {ListNode} l2
# @return {ListNode}
```

is the YARD documentation of the `add_two_numbers` method. It means that the method takes two parameters (`l1` and `l2`, both are `ListNode` instances) and returns a new `ListNode` instance.